# Why present continuous in this context?

Tags: grammar

My mother was in her room while I made a mess in kitchen. So she came and helped me make food. Then she said

> “I am watching a movie”

But wasn't she helping me in kitchen? Could she have meant

> “I am watching a movie so don't disturb me by causing mess”?

Or did she mean

> “I am going to watch a movie as soon as I'm done with this”?

But if she did mean the second one then she'd say

> “now I'm watching a movie”

that too right after leaving the kitchen and not while continuing on with the activity.

Comment: There's no requirement to structure your question as a poem. If you elect to do so, however, the unwritten rule *is* to make it rhyme.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask your mother what she meant?  Or is she still busy watching the movie?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the present continuous to describe an action you were doing and plan to continue doing but have been interrupted. The interruption doesn't even have to be for a short amount of time, I frequently hear it from coworkers who are describing things they've been doing in their free time, but can't be doing at the moment because of work. Even if you're on an extended trip of some sort, you can use the present continuous to describe things you were doing before you left and will continue doing when you return.